# CSS - How to make a div as wide as a containing child img

Tags: css

I have this simple markup for a div:

```
<div class="gallery__card">
    <img class="gallery__card__img" src="1.jpg">
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
</div>
```

But I want `gallery__card` to be as wide as `gallery__card__img`, so the text
below the image doesn't take the full page width.

[image]

I want to avoid setting fixed widths, since this is supposed to be responsive.

Is there a way to accomplish this without JS nor fixed widths?

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6h19oa1q/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `.gallery__card` is wider than `gallery__card__img`is because of the `text` you have in `.gallery__card`. If you remove the `text`, it will stay as wide as `.gallery__card__img`. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6h19oa1q/1/).

You can set you `img`s to have `width: 100%` and remove your static `height` property like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6h19oa1q/3/), but then you have to make sure to maintain aspect ratios of all the images you are using; or you will have differing `height`s (if that's an issue).

Otherwise, you have to change the way you are constructing your elements.

Comment: Or set a width to the `.gallery__car` and then `.gallery__card__img` width:100% and height: auto;

Comment: @MattiaNocerino `height: auto` is implied, also the OP wanted to avoid fixed widths, but certainly that is an option as well.

Answer (score 3):

The non-fixed width thing seems to be out of the question here, when you make a `div` element `display: inline-block` it will resize to it's "biggest" child which in this case is text that doesn't wrap without a width constraint either.

As **@Quoid** mentioned in his answer you can also make the images scale to `width: 100%` or `height: 100%` depending on what you need<sup>[1,2]</sup>.

Another solution is to possibly not use [basic image tags](https://www.google.nl/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=object-fit&oq=object-fit&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1367j0j7) but instead use another `div` element with an *inline* `background-image: url(...)` property. How awful this sounds it's a good alternative if you want to have an image tag on steroids and aren't too OCD-ish about some inline CSS.

**Refs for aspect-ratio**

1. http://daverupert.com/2012/04/uncle-daves-ol-padded-box/
2. [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/how-to-maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-using-only-css)

Comment: `background-image` is a great method to use; wasn't sure if OP wanted to alter his structure though

Comment: Hence I put it in there as "another solution" It's always nice to give an alternative next to what the OP actually needs so that he has a lead if it's an absolute dead-end which in this case it is with this no-width-if-possible constraint :)

Comment: Oh, I completely agree w/you! My comment was meant to be a compliment!

Comment: @Quoid I know, don't worry - there was a context smiley attached: ":)"

Answer (score 2):

you can use JS (my solution is with using jQuery), in each iteration you are looking on child element with selector `img` and then setting up parent element width

```
$('.gallery__card').each(function() {
    var newWidth = $(this).children('img').width();
    $(this).width(newWidth);
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/cwp83vkq/

Comment: Why use js when you can easliy do it with css?

Comment: It is one possible solution, maybe is not the best one :) But it can help somebody. Is simple and clear on first look what I'm doing.

Comment: It is a nice trick to solve certain problems, but definitely the wrong way to solve this question. The OP mentioned clearly that he's pursuing responsive design and your JS solution makes it much harder to do so. This JS will get in the way when trying to add `@media` and other standard CSS techniques.

Comment: Sure, I understand and thanks for comments, but I think there is no super danger risk if i keep my answer here, someone can use it for his purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/6h19oa1q/5/

**CSS**

```
.gallery__card {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: table;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 1%
}

.text {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery__card__img {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should make exactly what you want. You can play around with the `width` of the parent element to make it fit a responsive layout.

**HTML**

```
    <a href='link/tofile.jpg'>
       <div class="gallery__card">
          <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
       </div>
    </a>
```

**CSS**

```
      .gallery_card {
       width: 300px;
       border: 1px solid #000;
       margin: 0 auto;
       height: 300px;
       background: url('link/tofile.jpg');
       background-size: cover;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       position: relative;
    }

      .gallery_card .text {
       position: absolute;
       color: #000;
       text-decoration: none;
       text-align: center;
       background-color: #fff;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       padding-top: 5px;
       padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
```

Comment: 2 problems with this one, one is that it's what the OP is trying to **avoid** `width` regardless of being a valid solution and the other is that the text probably has to be responsive too which becomes alot more difficult to handle with `position: absolute` (not major but still, not everyone **knows** positioning in CSS)

Comment: +1 for the `width`, but i don't see a problem using `position: absolute`. In it's current state without a height or a width it merely fixes the text in the bottom and expands to fit the content with some padding.

Comment: `position: absolute` also removes the element from document flow for as far as `relative` parents go anyways, I'm just re-reading this now and actually agree with `position: absolute` being ok-ish, even tho it's not a complete example it can work in a responsive design.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paravibe/jma17x8t/)

Add this style to all images that you have

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

And remove all height restrictions from `.gallery__card__img`

Comment: What's the point in specifying the maximum width to be 100%? It's redundant. More importantly, stretching the images beyond their actual size will make them look blurry.

Comment: @RacilHilan `max-width` and `width` can be redundant, but nothing about `width` stretches the images beyond their actual size unless the `width: 100%` reaches a pixel width greater than the dimensions of the image This is a precaution the user should take when using `width: 100%` - having this `width` value is perfectly appropriate, useful and acceptable

Comment: Yes, of course having the `width` value at 100% is perfectly OK if that's what the design requires. However, having the `max-width` also set to 100% is redundant and that's absolutely not OK.

Answer (score 1):

You also define the width in responsive designs, but you just base it on percentage or other similar methods. In your case, you can set the container's width to some percentage like 50%, and set the maximum size to the actual size of the images (because they will look blurry if you stretch them beyond their actual size) which is `500px`, then set the width of the images to 100% of the container:

```css
.gallery {
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid red; /* This is just for testing */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* This is just for testing */
}
.wrapper {
}
.gallery__card {
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.gallery__card__img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="gallery__card">
            <img class="gallery__card__img width-1" src="http://www.cbre.us/o/losangelesmarket/AssetLibrary/GreaterLosAngelesMarket_mainimage.jpg">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
        </div>
         <div class="gallery__card">
            <img class="gallery__card__img width-1" src="http://students.marshall.usc.edu/undergrad/files/2012/04/Selling-Your-Los-Angeles-Home1.jpeg">
            <div class="text">Sed at elit nec ligula pellentesque congue eget a elit. Sed in purus nisi. Nulla dapibus non est ac lacinia. Suspendisse potenti.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```